# Porque los check no se muestran?

Tags: php, mysql

actualmente con este código:

```
>   $user_a_p =
>                     $sql5 = "select * from as_users"; 
>                     $ds5 = mysqli_query($con, $sql5);
>                     while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds5)){ echo  $asignacion_p_2 = $fila['email'] ==  $userInfo['email'] ? ' <input
> type="checkbox" name="compradores"  id="compradores">
> '.$fila["username"] : '';
```

tengo este resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual es excelente es justo lo que necesito... Pero necesito que aparezca en la ventana modal de cada producto... Sin embargo lo que aparece es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo llamo con esta variable:

> $user_a_p;

Entonces si cambio la variable a $asignacion_p_2 sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo aparece un Check, como podría visualizar los checks que aparecen en la primera imagen ??

#### Código Completo :

```
<?php
       
          $ano_ac = strftime('%d/%m/%Y');
          $hora_actual=strftime("%H:%M:%S");
                                
          $asignar_p = $userInfo['email'];
                               
                               
          $liderB = $userInfo['user_role'] == 9 ? '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn" >Generar Pedido</button> ' :  '<button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" disabled >No es lider</button>'; 
                               
          $user_a_p = $sql5 = "select * from as_users"; 
          $ds5 = mysqli_query($con, $sql5);
          while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds5)){
           
                               echo  $asignacion_p_2 = $fila['email'] ==  $userInfo['email'] ? ' <input type="checkbox" name="compradores"  id="compradores"> '.$fila["username"] : ''; }; 
                                 
                                 $sql = "select * from as_productos"; 
                                 $ds = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                 while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ds)){
                                     echo " 
                               
                          <div class='col-sm-3 col-md-3'>
           <div class='thumbnail' >
             <img style='width:300px;height:150px;' src='{$fila['img_producto']}' alt='...'>
             <div class='caption'>
               <h3>{$fila['titulo_producto']} </h3>
               <p>{$fila['descripcion_producto']}</p>
               <p><strong>PRECIO:</strong> $ <span style='color:green;'> {$fila['precio']}</span></p>
               
                
               <p>Disponible hasta las {$fila['hora_max_producto']}</p></p>
              <a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#{$fila['id']}' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'> Comprar</span></a>
             </div>
           </div>
             <br>
         </div>           
       
          <form method='post' action=''>
       <!-- Modal -->
       <div style='font-size:16px;' class='modal fade' id='{$fila['id']}' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
         <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
           <div class='modal-content'>
             <div class='modal-header'>
               <h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel' style='font-size:18px;'>Realizar Orden</h5>
               </button>
             </div>
             <div class='modal-body'>
             <div class='panel panel-default'>
               <strong style='width:25px;'>Producto: </strong> 
             
               <input type='text' value='{$fila['titulo_producto']}' name='nombreproducto' style='background-color:white;border:none;' readonly placeholder='{$fila['titulo_producto']}'></input><br>
             <br>
              <img style='width:400px;border-radius:10px;' src='{$fila['img_producto']}' alt='' /><br><br>
       
               <strong>Precio: </strong>
               
               $<input type='text'  value='{$fila['precio']}' name='precio' style='background-color:white;border:none;' readonly placeholder='{$fila['precio']}'></input><br>
               
               
                <strong>Tipo de Entrega: </strong> 
             
               <select style='padding:3px;border-radius:5px;' type='text' name='entrega' >
               
                <option value='Empacado'>Empacado</option>
               <option value='NO Empacado'>NO Empacado</option>
               
               </select><br>
                </div>
                
               
               
             <div class='panel panel-default'>
            <h4>Info de facturación</h4>
            
             <strong>Fecha: </strong> <input value='$ano_ac, Hora: $hora_actual' name='fpg' type='text'  style='background-color:white;border:none;' readonly placeholder='$ano_ac, Hora: $hora_actual'></input><br>
              
               <strong>Nombre: </strong> <input value='{$userDetails['first_name']}' name='nombrecomprador' type='text'  style='background-color:white;border:none;' readonly placeholder='{$userDetails['first_name']}'></input><br>
               
               <strong>Entidad: </strong><input type='text' value='{$userDetails['last_name']}' name='entidad' style='background-color:white;border:none;' readonly placeholder='{$userDetails['last_name']}'></input><br>
               
               
                <strong style='display:none;'>Status: </strong>
               <input  type='text' value='Pendiente' name='status' style='background-color:white;border:none;display:none;' readonly placeholder='pendiente'></input>
               </div>
              
               <div class='panel panel-default'>
         <div class='panel-heading'>Asignar Pedidos {$asignar_p}</div>
            
         <div class='panel-body'>
         $user_a_p
         </div>
       </div>
                </div>        
             <div class='modal-footer'>
           
               <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button> 
               $liderB
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
        </form>
                                     ";
                                 }
                                 
                                 ?>
```

**URL :** https://pastebin.com/6wmSUXGw

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. De entrada, no puedes asignar el mismo `id` a más de un elemento. Sea como sea, pulsa en [edit] y trata de explicar mejor lo que quieres hacer, mostrando el código implicado. Evita capturas de pantalla, poniendo mejor el texto de los resultados o errores que obtienes.

Comment: Actualizado!! Espero ser lo mas claro posible

Comment: Aún no se entiende. Pon el código que tienes antes y después del `while`. Parece que estás haciendo un echo de la variable `$sql5`. Tampoco dices si ese es el código del modal ¿? Pon el código tal y como lo tienes en tu editor, sin esto delante de cada línea `>`. Puedes copiar, pegar, luego seleccionas todo el bloque de código y pulsas en `{ }` para que quede tabulado.

Comment: Dime qué piensas que estás guardando en esta variable: `$user_a_p =`, donde a continuación sigues haciendo otras asignaciones: `$sql5 = "select * from as_users";`. Esa asignación que haces para `$user_a_p` no tiene mucho sentido si no le asignas nada y a continuación haces otra asignación diferente... Básicamente estás metiendo ahí lo mismo que en `$sql5`, no el resultado de la ejecución de esa query! `a = b = "hola"` va a hacer que ambas valgan `"hola"`, que es lo que estás haciendo tú. Tampoco deberías hacer un `echo` de una asignación... te recomiendo que repases un poco la base de php :)

Comment: Claro, entiendo el punto ya depuré esa variable de mi código;